# b'No files matched pattern error with Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, directory-structure

I started to write the code below to review my dataset by using tensorflow. I'm tried to load the images to tensorflow. So I add the relative path as you can see below.

```
import tensorflow as tf

gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for gpu in gpus:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)


print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))

images = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('data\\images\\*.jpg',shuffle=False)
```

But I got the error below.

```
Expected 'tf.Tensor(False, shape=(), dtype=bool)' to be true. Summarized data: b'No files matched pattern:: data\\images\\*.jpg'
```

You can see my folder hierarchy below. I think my path is correct. There are multiple images with .jpg format in the images folder.

[image]

I also tried to change my path to variations below but none of it worked.

```
'\\data\\images\\*.jpg'
'/data/images/*.jpg'
'data/images/*.jpg'
```

What I am missing here, can you help me out please?

**UPDATE:**

Eventually, I couldn't make it work with relative path, so I go with the full absolute path and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

You can import the inside images from the folder by giving the last image folder path to the [list_files()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#list_files) as below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files("/Users/renupatel/Desktop/Training_dataset/Cats/*.jpeg", shuffle=False)

for f in list_ds.take(5):
    print(f.numpy())
```

Output:

```
b'/Users/renupatel/Desktop/Training_dataset/Cats/Cat1.jpeg'
b'/Users/renupatel/Desktop/Training_dataset/Cats/Cat10.jpeg'
b'/Users/renupatel/Desktop/Training_dataset/Cats/Cat2.jpeg'
b'/Users/renupatel/Desktop/Training_dataset/Cats/Cat3.jpeg'
b'/Users/renupatel/Desktop/Training_dataset/Cats/Cat4.jpeg'
```

Please refer to this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#consuming_sets_of_files) for more details on importing set of files.